# issue in adding order item in infusionsoft

Tags: php, infusionsoft

i am adding an orderitem in infusionsoft api.. but i am getting syntax error but i m not able to find out.

```
 require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/infusionsoftAPI/src/isdk.php");
 $app = new iSDK;

 $_REQUEST['contactId'] = 4;

 if(!empty($_REQUEST['contactId']))
 {
    if ($app->cfgCon("aaaa", 'eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee')) {
        echo "Infusionsoft Connection Successfulls";
    } else {
        echo "Infusionsoft Connection Failed";
        exit;
    }
} else {
    echo '<p>No contact id selected.</p>';
    exit();
}
some code
some code
$invoiceId = $app->blankOrder($contactId,"Video Report Subscription - Extra", $oDate,0,0);
$extra_price = $extraemail * $result['price_after_expire'];

$ordresult = $app->addOrderItem($invoiceId, 4, 9, $extra_price, 1, "helloo", "aaaaaa");
```

i am getting this error

> ERROR: -1 - No method matching arguments:
>   java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer,
>   java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer,
>   java.lang.String, java.lang.String

But when i write

```
  $ordresult = $app->addOrderItem($invoiceId, 4, 9, 22.00, 1, "helloo", "aaaaaa");
```

it works....
the issue is that it is not getting $extra_price as its argument..

Comment: See if this works: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28828493/1724702

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `$extra_price` is an integer, but `addOrderItem` expects a float.
Try:

> $ordresult = $app->addOrderItem($invoiceId, 4, 9, floatval($extra_price), 1, "helloo", "aaaaaa");

Reference: [InvoiceService addOrderItem API](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/read/Invoice_Service#addOrderItem)